# Entry and LinkedLists, best way to iterate through them?

Tags: java, android, linked-list

I am receiving a ClassCastException while trying to cast a LinkedList to a Map or HashMap. I have the following LinkedList:

```
List<Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<Integer, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
```

and I am trying to iterate through this list doing the following:

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = ((Map<Integer, Integer>) list).entrySet().iterator(); // this is problematic code
if (iter.hasNext()) {
   //do some stuff
}
```

What is the proper way of doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can just iterate list, from your limited code I don't see the need of map, all you want to do is iterate over a list

`for (Entry<Integer, Integer> e : list){  
   e.getKey() ; 
   e.getValue();
}   
`

Comment: Why are you using a `LinkedList` at all? What's wrong with `for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())`?

Comment: I am using a LinkedList to maintain order

Comment: @portfoliobuilder I still don't understand. Can you give a broader idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: The linkedList holds a specific pattern of integers that I want to maintain in that order to use later. I am then trying to use this pattern to create other patterns but got stuck while iterating through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the cast. The `iterator` method of the list will return an `Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>>` as you want. This is because the `List` type is generic. So whatever the type of the element in the list will also be the type argument of the `Iterator`.

Also in order to loop, you probably need a `while` instead of an `if`:

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    //do some stuff with entry
}
```

or using a `for` loop to limit the scope of the `Iterator` to just the body of the loop:

```
for (Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    //do some stuff with entry
}
```

You could also do this with the existing map. There's no need to create a `LinkedList` and fill all those entries if you just want to iterate over them:

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
```

Comment: for loop is preferred since it limits the scope of the iterator

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to cast the list to a map to iterate through it.
You can just use something like this:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> currentEntry = iter.next();
    //do some stuff
}
```

Note that to iterate through the list you have to use the while loop, not the conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

Just use for a `for` loop. Creating a new list is inefficient both memory and processor wise.

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
}
```